# Number of possible analysis for lat, long, data for different periods in R

Tags: r, csv, import-from-csv

I have a dataset here with latitude, longitude and salinity for an area. I have these data for three different cases. First case is for normal flow conditions, second is for high flow and third case is for waterlevelrise.

I want to understand how can we use these data and then make some type of analysis.

My data set is uploaded on https://www.dropbox.com/s/285iuyv6bugm48p/dataanalysisforthreetimes.csv

Some of the things that come up to my mind are:

1. Find the increase or decrease of salinity for each time or even say a pattern.
2. Mean salinity under different conditions

The code that I used to start in **R** is as follows:

```
mydata <- read.csv("dataanalysisforthreetimes.csv")
head(mydata)
library(reshape2)
data1 <- melt(mydata,"Lat","Long")
```

Would you suggest if I can fit any linear model to my data? Any suggested techniques are highly appreciated.
I want to use **R** to do the analysis. Can you suggest any reading as well?

Comment: flagged for migration to [cross validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)...

Comment: what does it mean by flagged for mig ?

Comment: if you make this less of a *"how can should I analyse my data"* question and more of a *"here is an example of my data I am trying to this specifically, but cannot find how to do it"*, you will probably get an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I would try to rephrase my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mean salinity for all three conditions:

```
data1 <- melt(mydata,id=c("Lat","Long"))

aggregate(value ~ variable, mean, data=data1)
#   variable     value
#1  Highflow  4.039384
#2 Levelrise 32.238867
#3    Normal 21.153334
```

here is how you get the mean fro your conditions. As for linear models, you are probably best googling linear models with spatial autocorrelation in R to get your started.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. May be this time I didn't put up question properly. I will try to make questions more precise and clear next time.